# How to highlight the min and max value in a row wise manner?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

In LibreOffice Calc (6.0) I try to highlight the minimum and maximum of each row in group of column (col A to E)? Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

An easy and quick way to solve this problem is to use [**Format - Conditional Formatting**](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.0/en-US/text/scalc/01/05120000.html).

Use **Formula is** with expressions like `A1=MIN($A1:$E1)` and `A1=MAX($A1:$E1)`

Please be careful - references to column names in the formula must be absolute, with a dollar sign **$**. Also pay attention to the address of the checked cell (underlined in red in the screenshot)

[image: Conditional_Formatting_MIN_MAX.png]